# Vector push_back happens randomly

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I have a pretty weird error while trying to implement a board game in QT. This is my second time, having the same issue, and now i think it's time to ask here.

I'm still at the game's logic part, which have a class named Field, and a class named Board. The Board class has a `QVector < Field* > fields` attribute, which is a vector of `Field` pointers. And here is the problem. I have a function which supposed to upload this vector with new Fields. Here is my source, it's pretty straight forward:

```
void Board::addFields()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) //the board's size is size x size
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<size; j++)
        {
            Field * f = new Field();
            fields.push_back(f);
            //qDebug()<<i*size+j<<" "<<f;
        }
    }
    //qDebug()<<fields.size();
}
```

And after i got a ton of weird errors, i decided to write to the console the actual number of elements, the reference of the actual element, and after the two loop the size of the vector.

The result was pretty strange, i got no errors, but somtimes it added all my elements, sometimes it stopped at a random number of elements, and the size of the vector doesnt even got printed out like this:

result 1 (normal):

0   0xa173a8

...

24   0x701c18

25

result 2 (??? every time with a different number of elements):

0   0xa173a8

...

12   0xa17548

//and no vector size, i assume the function got a return; because of something

I tried it with both QVector, and std::vector, it's the same. Please if someone got any idea, what the problem could be, tell me!

Thanks, and sorry for my english!

**EDIT**

All my code is here:

field.h: http://paste2.org/p/1937231

field.cpp: http://paste2.org/p/1937232

player.h: http://paste2.org/p/1937238

player.cpp: http://paste2.org/p/1937239

board.h: http://paste2.org/p/1937234

board.cpp: http://paste2.org/p/1937235

main.cpp: http://paste2.org/p/1937243

Comment: how and where is `fields` declared?

Comment: fields is declared in the Board class as a private attribute. 
( private: QVector <Field*> fields; )

Comment: can you post more code? which weird errors did you get and where were they?

Comment: the problem is most likely elsewhere

Comment: The weird thing is the second part of my post: the two loops are not always appending the same amount of elements, and if the are not inserting enough elements, the function stops. Look at the output examples. But if you would like, i can post the code of the other classes.

Comment: "..and no vector size, i assume the function got a return; because of something".  There's no such thing as an implicit return through multiple levels of the stack. Unless you have exceptions that aren't being caught or some other form of non-local control flow going on, almost certainly what's happening is that you're getting a crash somewhere. Perhaps the constructor for Field is failing at random times. QVector can also move your elements around; I wouldn't think moving a pointer would hurt, but it's possible I suppose, depending on what Field contains.

Comment: The fact that you're getting different results each time means you're probably relying on undefined behaviour somewhere. Are there any errors when it fails? Or does it just suddenly end?

Comment: Bot the `new Field` and the `push_back` code could throw. Do you silently catch exceptions? This could explain the fact the size was not printed at the end: In normal circonstances, the exception would make your app crash, but if you catch them (in the game main loop, for example), then the app silently continue.

Comment: Are you  sure the problem is there?

Comment: Ok, all my code is here: 

field.h: http://paste2.org/p/1937231
 
field.cpp: http://paste2.org/p/1937232 

player.h: http://paste2.org/p/1937238

player.cpp: http://paste2.org/p/1937239

board.h: http://paste2.org/p/1937234

board.cpp: http://paste2.org/p/1937235

main.cpp: http://paste2.org/p/1937243

Comment: no, i didn't expected exceptions, but now i will check it. And no, no runtime or compile errors where show in the state i shown you.

Comment: ok, there are no std::exceptions thrown in the problematic part.

Comment: do `qDebug() << size;` before the loop to check if size is correct for the case where it goes wrong.

Comment: I've tested your code now on Ubuntu 11.10, both 64-bit and 32-bit. I see nothing in it that should cause this.

I however noticed that the code you posted won't compile as-is (missing headers), so it seems you _might_ have a contaminated build-environment.

I threw together a clean build for you with qmake, https://rapidshare.com/files/3141791124/game.tar.gz. You should be able to just download this, and "qmake && make". See if it works.

Otherwise, my best bet is you are using a broken library, or broken compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Everyone for the help, i found the solution.

Since i was making the logic part of a window application, i started a QT gui project. It generated for me a main() function with this:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();
return a.exec();
```

I didn't know what this is, but because i didn't need any windows for now, i removed the code, and replaced it with my code, and a simple return 0; at the end. This must have caused the problem, because when i added the QApplication to the code again:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
Board b(10);
return a.exec();
```

It worked like a charm...

I don't know what to do in this case, if i could, i would give the point to all of you, who tried to help. But anyways, thank you very much for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you type `new Field();` you make a dynamic memory allocation. The returned pointer actually is quite random, and you should not rely on it to be sequential. But normally that is no problem.

> And after i got a ton of weird errors, i decided to write to the console the actual number of elements, the reference of the actual element, and after the two loop the size of the vector.

What errors are you experiencing exactly?

Comment: I have gotten errors when i tried to access the elements of the vector. But because they didn't always got added, it generated errors. Now i don't try to access the elements, so i don't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is `size` a member? for my experience if things happen randomly it's 98% caused by members not initialized..

Comment: are you sure `Board::Board(int size):size(size)` thing doesn t create problems? use different names for initialization...

Comment: i checked your code and it doesn t show problems.. i only made some initialization in a safer way i.e `Board::Board(int size_):size(size_), fields(), playerOne(0),playerTwo(0)` and `Field::Field(Player *player_) : player(player_)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know details of object initialization in C++, but

```
Board::Board(int size):size(size)
{
   playerOne = new Player("Player One");
   playerTwo = new Player("Player Two");
   newGame(this->size);
}
```

may be the cause of the trouble. indeed, newGame use `fields` which is not explicitely initialized. So try using

```
 Board::Board(int size):size(size), fields(size*size) //or just fields()
 {
  ...
  }
```

And tell us what happens.

Comment: I tried this: Board::Board(int s):size(s), fields(s*s) {...}
Still the same... :(